# How does -H work in the ssh-keyscan command?

Tags: ssh, openssh

About the `ssh-keyscan` command for the `-H` option according with:

- [ssh-keyscan — gather ssh public keys](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ssh-keyscan.1.html)

it indicates

```
 -H      Hash all hostnames and addresses in the output.  Hashed names may be used normally
         by ssh and sshd, but they do not reveal identifying information should the file's
         contents be disclosed.
```

I don't understand neither the idea nor its purpose. It is the reason of this post.
Please Can you clarity its use?

I did realize for two different hosts, that if is executed

```
# Pair I
ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.x
ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.y

# Pair II
ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.1.x
ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.1.y
```

The **first** pair: for each IP, the output for each public key appears and indicating the key type as `dsa, ecdsa, ed25519` and `rsa`.

The **second** pair: for each IP, the output for each public key appears, and indicating the key type as `dsa, ecdsa, ed25519` and `rsa` - however appears at the beginning for each key type the `|1|` text with some random text

**Question:**

- How does `-H` work in the `ssh-keyscan` command?

**Extra Questions**

- When is mandatory use `-H`?
- What does `|1|`  *with some random text* mean?

Remember, `|1|` *with some random text* appears in the output for two different hosts, it for each key type. So I am assuming it is not a coincidence

**Note**

I am not sharing the outputs just for security reasons

Comment: Do you understand what a "hash" is? See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function.

Comment: @thrig thanks for your comment, without be rude, it that the unique scenario? - if yes, please put your comment as an answer with some expanded details, it to let me mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one-way hashing is advertised as a means to make it more difficult for an attacker to know what hosts you SSH to should said attacker get their hands on your `known_hosts` file. Here is what `ssh_config(5)` says:

```
 HashKnownHosts
         Indicates that ssh(1) should hash host names and addresses when
         they are added to ~/.ssh/known_hosts.  These hashed names may be
         used normally by ssh(1) and sshd(8), but they do not visually re-
         veal identifying information if the file's contents are dis-
         closed.  The default is no.
```

This is security through obscurity, though leans towards "good obscurity" as it may make it more difficult for an attacker to find additional hosts to target, or for someone to know that you have been connecting to an politically inapropriate system. There are other ways to find this information (firewall logs, network flow records, DNS, etc), but an easily read unhashed text file is great for an attacker, and the other means may not be available or may take too long.

(You should probably also encrypt the disk for better "defense in depth", though that will not help if an application exploit allows direct access to the mounted filesystem, or if they find your screen unlocked, etc.)

Comment: Please, consider to add the `ssh_config(5)` link. Thanks for your expanded explanation. Now has more sense the `-H` option. After to did do a research this `-H` is used _mostly_ when an "entry" is added to the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.